# Is it possible to create part of activity transparent and not clickable?

Tags: android, android-activity, transparent

Is it possible to create part of an activity transparent and not clickable? I mean i want to create activity with transparent area so that another activity under my activity would be clickable. I know about fragments approach but i need similar behavior with activities because another activity will be from another application.

Answer (score 0):

In the xml layout file, add this to the parent view

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

Then inside the activity tag in your AndroidManfiest.xml, change the

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
```

Also in the activity you want to be in the overlay style, implement the OnBackPressed() without implementing the super.blah, so that when the back button is pressed, it won't affect your activity, instead it would affect the activity in the background of your app.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
   //Don't add any super.onBackPressed();
}
```

It is also advisable to make your xml layout to be wrap content on both width and height if you didn't know that already :)

Comment: Your solution does not address the "so that another activity under my activity would be clickable" part.